# Parent server fork needs to exit in timely fashion

Tags: python, fork, exit

I have this server draft that forks new children after a new client connection. Then depends on a client’s command child server does some work inside the function handler(connection).

In the meantime, I want to stop the parent server and before that let the parent wait for all working children.

The question is where shall I place this signal function for the `Ctrl+C` keyboard interrupt option.
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

```
children_list = []
conn = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
conn.bind((HOST, PORT))
conn.listen(5)
print("Listening on TCP port %s" % PORT)

def reaper(pids):   

        while children_list:                        
        pid,stat = os.waitpid(0, os.WNOHANG)   

        if not pid: 

            break

        pids.remove(pid)


def handler(connection):                    

    cmd = connection.recv(socksize)

def signal_handler(signal, frame):
    print 'You pressed Ctrl+C!'
    sys.exit(0)

def accept():                                

while 1:   
        global connection                                  
          connection, address = conn.accept()
          print "welcome new client!"
        reaper(children_list)
          pid = os.fork()                     
          if pid:#parent
              children_list.append(pid)
              connection.close()

         else:#child    
               handler(connection)


accept()
```

Comment: It would really help to fix the indentation so this is both readable and runnable. As it is, I can _guess_ what it's doing, but it would be better if I didn't have to.

Comment: And as a side note, any particular reason you're using `fork` instead of `threading`? There are plenty of good reasons (e.g., if the children aren't like typical server handlers that mostly wait around on I/O, but have lots of CPU work to do… or if you want to detach them so you can shut down the acceptor but leave existing clients running… etc.), but I'm curious what your reason is.

Comment: And one last side note: A TCP server usually wants to call `conn.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)` before calling `bind`. (See [here](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml) for the ancient FAQ, and [here](http://hea-www.harvard.edu/~fine/Tech/addrinuse.html) for more details.)

Comment: I need to use fork here...the threading is not what must be used...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The question is where shall I place this signal function for the Ctrl+C keyboard interrupt option. signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)

Anywhere you want, as long as it's after you define `signal_handler` and before you call `accept`.

I'm not sure that signal handler is actually what you want. What you're actually doing will, on most platforms, exit immediately, just as you're asking it to, causing the children to be reparented to `init` or `launchd` or similar. But you want to actually wait for all children. So, you can't call `exit`.

In POSIX, you're not allowed to call `waitpid` inside a signal hander. Python signal handlers aren't real signal handlers, so this *might* not be relevant—but I don't think that fact is guaranteed anywhere. If you want to take the risk, you could try waiting for all of the children right there in `signal_handler` before calling `exit` and see if it works on your platform.

However, the standard POSIX way to do it is to have the signal handler set some global flag and return. The main program will then wake up from `accept` or whatever other blocking call it's waiting on with an `EINTR` error, at which point it can check the flag—if true, time to wait on the children and quit; otherwise, go back into the loop and `accept` again.

But all of this shouldn't be necessary anyway. The default SIGINT handler should just raise a `KeyboardInterrupt`, which means that—if you don't install a custom signal handler—all you really need to do is catch that exception. In other words, just replace the last line with this:

```
try:
    accept()
except KeyboardInterrupt: # or maybe BaseException
    # wait for children, blocking instead of WNOHANG of course
    sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: I want to wait for all working children...as I put above "I want to stop the parent server and before that let the parent wait for all working children."

Comment: I tried to put signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler) "anywhere"...it just exits right the way and the parent does not wait for children...so getting errors.

Comment: @NatashaAlmazova: Yes, but that's not because of where you put the code, it's because your signal handler exits right away, by calling `sys.exit`. On most *nix platforms, that does exactly what you asked it to, causing the children to be reparented to `init` or `launchd` or similar. That's why I said "I'm not sure that signal handler is actually what you want."

Comment: @NatashaAlmazova: You can write a signal handler that will cause the `accept` to fail with an exception, which you could then catch and reap your children. But really, you don't need to; the default handler will already just raise a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception.

Comment: oh, so I need to re-do something...I need to find if number of active kids, then once it is zero, then allow to exit with signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal_handler)? is it possible? .....Sorry it is late here and I am slow...

Comment: I did not understand this part - "write a signal handler that will cause the accept to fail with an exception, which you could then catch and reap your children".....please explain more...